# How can I define this database relationship

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.1

I have 3 tables:
**venues**:
`id   |   name`

**locations**:
`id   |   address |   venue_id    |   city_id`

**cities**:
`id   |   name    |   slug        |   display_name`

a venue hasOne location, a location belongsTo a venue.
a location belongsTo a city,a city hasMany locations.

now, what's the relation between a venue and a city ?
how can I get queries from venue based on filtering city I mean execute "where" on city slug.
How can I get all venues from a city model?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`HasManyThrough`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship:

```php
class City extends Eloquent
{
    public function venues()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(App\Venue::class, App\Location::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Joseph Silber there should be location_id on cities table which there isn't

Comment: @Mehrdad - Oh right! What you're looking for is a `BelongsToThrough` relatioship. Unfortunately, [Laravel does not yet support that](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6161). You'll have to roll your own, or use [this](https://github.com/znck/belongs-to-through).

Comment: @ Joseph Silber how do you suggest to change architecture of this db?